# Lumen Debug Log not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, monolog

I'm using Lumen 5.3 and I'm not sure on how i should implement debug mode.

In .env, i have this:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

In my script I have this:

```
Log::debug("Test");
```

So it will log in storage/logs/lumen.log when i run the script which is right.

I have made the value of APP_DEBUG=false and yet the Log::debug line I put keeps logging in lumen.log. How to turn off the log in debug level or is any other way to implement what I'm expecting to happen?

Comment: What is it that you expect to happen? `APP_DEBUG` is used to indicate whether the errors should be seen on pages or not (`true` will show error call stack on the pages with errors, `false` will just return error code status page instead)

Comment: I see. Is there a way to stop Log::debug on logging in lumen.log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update for Lumen**

*Apologies* I was not reading properly, for Lumen 5.3 you can override the logging inside `bootstrap/app.php` pushing your own log handler.

Add the following towards the bottom of your app.php file, before you `return $app`:

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
...
$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {
    $handler = new StreamHandler(storage_path('logs/lumen.log'), Logger::ERROR);
    $handler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter(null, null, true, true));
    $monolog->pushHandler($handler);

    return $monolog;
});
```

In the code example you will then only be logging ERROR levels. You will need to import the namespaces.

*To disable logging completely, you can do the following*

```
$app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {
    $monolog->pushHandler(new NullHandler(Logger::DEBUG));

    return $monolog;
});
```

**Leaving the original Laravel 5.3 answer**

For laravel 5.3 the log level is configured inside `app/config.php`.

The default generally is

```
'log_level' => env('APP_LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
```

So if you change your `APP_LOG_LEVEL` inside the .env to something like `error` on your production server it will not log debug message sprinkled throughout the app.

Inside your .env

```
APP_LOG_LEVEL=error
```

Comment: Sorry but it's Lumen 5.3?

Comment: Does it mean that in my script, if I put all the log levels and add the configuration you sent, only Log::error will work or all the other Log levels below the Error in Lumen documentation?

Comment: The order of importance is ```debug, info, notice, warning, error, critical, alert, emergency```. So if you put ```Logger::ERROR```, debug, info, notice and warning will be ignored and only error, critical, alert and emergency will be written.

Comment: i have another question. How will i turn off the logging?

Comment: Well that is another question ;-) I updated my answer.